# How do I control number formatting in the python interpreter?

Tags: python, ipython

I often use the python interpreter for doing quick numerical calculations and would like all numerical results to be automatically printed using, e.g., exponential notation.  Is there a way to set this for the entire session?

For example, I want:

```
>>> 1.e12
1.0e+12
```

not:

```
>>> 1.e12
1000000000000.0
```

Comment: Very similar to [python - How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a Python script called whatever you want (say `mystartup.py`) and then set an environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` to the path of this script. Python will then load this script on startup of an interactive session (but not when running scripts). In this script, define a function similar to this:

```
def _(v):
    if type(v) == type(0.0):
        print "%e" % v
    else:
        print v
```

Then, in an interactive session:

```
C:\temp>set PYTHONSTARTUP=mystartup.py

C:\temp>python
ActivePython 2.5.2.2 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Mar 27 2008, 17:57:18) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> _(1e12)
1.000000e+012
>>> _(14)
14
>>> _(14.0)
1.400000e+001
>>>
```

Of course, you can define the function to be called whaetver you want and to work exactly however you want.

Even better than this would be to use [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/). It's great, and you can set the number formatting how you want by using `result_display.when_type(some_type)(my_print_func)` (see the IPython site or search for more details on how to use this).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for necroposting, but this topic shows up in related google searches and I believe a satisfactory answer is missing here.

I believe the right way is to use [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook). For example, you could add code like this in your `PYTHONSTARTUP` file:

```py
import builtins
import sys
import numbers


__orig_hook = sys.displayhook

def __displayhook(value):
    if isinstance(value, numbers.Number) and value >= 1e5:
        builtins._ = value
        print("{:e}".format(value))
    else:
        __orig_hook(value)

sys.displayhook = __displayhook
```

This will display large enough values using the exp syntax. Feel free to modify the threshold as you see fit.

Alternatively you can have the answer printed in both formats for large numbers:

```py
def __displayhook(value):
    __orig_hook(value)
    if isinstance(value, numbers.Number) and value >= 1e5:
        print("{:e}".format(value))
```

Or you can define yourself another answer variable besides the default `_`, such as `__` (such creativity, I know):

```py
builtins.__ = None
__orig_hook = sys.displayhook

def __displayhook(value):
    if isinstance(value, numbers.Number):
        builtins.__ = "{:e}".format(value)
    __orig_hook(value)

sys.displayhook = __displayhook
```

... and then display the exp-formatted answer by typing just `__`.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. This can be easily applied to a lot of things. Do you want a binary representation for easy bitwise fun? Try `"{:b}"`!  Hex? `"{:x}"` Wand some color? `"\033[91m {:e}\033[00m"`.

Answer (score 1):

As you know you can use [the `%` operator](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html) or [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to format strings:

For example:

```
>>> "%e" % 1.e12
'1.000000e+12'
```

I was wondering if you could [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the built-in `float` class to change the formatting but it seems that Python won't let you:

```
>>> 1.e12.__class__.__repr__ = lambda x: "%e" % x
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'float'
```

So the only other thing I can think of is to write your own file-like object which captures output, reformats it and sends it to the standard output.  You'd then redirect standard output of the interpreter to this object:

```
sys.stdout = my_formatting_object
```

Comment: Yes, but I do not want to have to type this with every input.  Since I want the same formatting for the entire session I would like to set it once and not bother with it anymore.

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, didn't read your question properly.  Have expanded the answer to cover your question properly, as far as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Hm... It's not a 100% solution, but this have come to my mind...

How about defining a subclass of float which would have an overridden `__str__` method (to print with the exp notation). And then you would have to wrap all the expressions with object construction of this class).
It would be a bit shorter than Dave's solution, you would define the class once and then write something like:

```
>>> F(1.e12)
1.0e+12
>>> F(3.)
3.0e+0
>>> F(1.+2.+3.+4.)
1.0e+1
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Dave Webb's hint above. You can of course set the precision if you like ("%.3e") and perhaps override writelines if needed.

```
import os
import sys

class ExpFloatFileObject:
    def write(self, s):
        try:
            s = "%e"%float(s)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        sys.__stdout__.write(s)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(sys.__stdout__, name)

sys.stdout = ExpFloatFileObject()
```

and usage:

```
>>> 14000    
1.400000e+04  
>>> "text"
'text'
```

Answer (score 0):

When using IPython/Jupyter-console, the "magic" command `%precision %e` will change the display of raw floats in exponential notation. https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-precision

For more formatting control, a formatter can be registered:

```
excited_floats = lambda val: "{:e}!!!".format(val)
console_formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
console_formatter.for_type(float, lambda val, p, c: p.text(excited_floats(val)))
```

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html#IPython.core.formatters.PlainTextFormatter