# How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format?

Tags: python, ipython

Here's the default behavior:

```
In [21]: 255
Out[21]: 255
```

And here's what I would like:

```
In [21]: 255
Out[21]: FF
```

Can I setup ipython to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this post](http://www.stackoverflow.com/q/1187000/20009616).

Comment: Related: [Python console default hex display](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6307433/4518341)

Comment: Related question: [When I am in the Python or IPython console, what is called when I am returned an output? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28304092/when-i-am-in-the-python-or-ipython-console-what-is-called-when-i-am-returned-an?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this by registering a special display formatter for ints:

```
In [1]: formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']

In [2]: formatter.for_type(int, lambda n, p, cycle: p.text("%X" % n))
Out[2]: <function IPython.lib.pretty._repr_pprint>

In [3]: 1
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: 100
Out[4]: 64

In [5]: 255
Out[5]: FF
```

If you want this always-on, you can create a file in `$(ipython locate profile)/startup/hexints.py` with the first two lines (or as one to avoid any assignments):

```
get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(int, lambda n, p, cycle: p.text("%X" % n))
```

which will be executed every time you start IPython.

Comment: Even better: print both representations! `formatter.for_type(int, lambda n, p, cycle: p.text("%d (0x%X)" % (n,n)))`

Comment: This suggestion is awesome, will save me cumulative hours of typing `hex(...)` to get results in hex format.

Comment: What does `cycle` do in the lambda definition?

Comment: I tried removing `cycle`, got an error, and looked at the relevant source code. It seems it's irrelevant in this case, but has something to do with printing iterables.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [minrk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14993580/4518341) and [rjb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43618365/4518341) on another question, I put this in my Python startup file:

```
def hexon_ipython():
  '''To print ints as hex, run hexon_ipython().
  To revert, run hexoff_ipython().
  '''
  formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
  formatter.for_type(int, lambda n, p, cycle: p.text("0x%x" % n))


def hexoff_ipython():
  '''See documentation for hexon_ipython().'''
  formatter = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
  formatter.for_type(int, lambda n, p, cycle: p.text("%d" % n))


hexon = hexon_ipython
hexoff = hexoff_ipython
```

So I can use it like this:

```
In [1]: 15
Out[1]: 15

In [2]: hexon()

In [3]: 15
Out[3]: 0xf

In [4]: hexoff()

In [5]: 15
Out[5]: 15
```