# IPython display a string without the quote mark

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is there a way to use IPyhton display to print a string without printing the quotation marks?

```
from IPython.display import display

label = display('Hello world!', display_id = True)
```

The output is:

```
'Hello world!'
```

It included the quote marks. I don't want to print it as an HTML like this:

```
display(HTML('Hello wolrd!'), display_id = True)
```

Comment: It's possible to use `display_formatter` to do this automatically: [python - How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format)

Answer (score 3):

display is quite smart, it could display many formats, but by default it uses __repr__ of the object you pass (but you could also define for example _repr_html_, _repr_json_ etc., check this for more information: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html ).

This is how you could solve your problem:

```py
class printer(str):
    def __repr__(self):
       return self
    
handle = display(printer('Hello world!'), display_id=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try print():

```
print('Hello world!')
```

Result:

```
Hello world!
```

Comment: print() doesn't give me the opportunity to update a specific printed line, whilst display() can. Imagine having multiple prints each one prints to a separate line and want to update only one of them. With display() you can reference a certain label with its ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
display(HTML('<pre>Hello wolrd!</pre>'), display_id = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite String formmater (similar to the example on display docstring with an int):

```
from IPython.display import display

def str_formatter(string, pp, cycle):
    pp.text(string)

plain = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
plain.for_type(str, str_formatter)

display("Hello World!")
```