# ipython: print numbers with thousands separator

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, ipython, python-3.7

I am using `ipython` `5.8.0` on `Debian 10`.

This is how output looks like:

```
In [1]: 50*50
Out[1]: 2500
```

Is it possible to configure `ipython` to print all numbers with thousands separators? ie:

```
In [1]: 50*50
Out[1]: 2'500

In [2]: 5000*5000
Out[2]: 25'000'000
```

And perhaps, is it possible to make `ipython` also understand thousands separators on input?

```
In [1]: 5'000*5'000
Out[1]: 25'000'000
```

## UPDATE

The accepted answer from `@Chayim Friedman` works for integers, but does not work for float:

```
In [1]: 500.1*500
Out[1]: 250050.0
```

Also, when it works, it uses `,` as the character for thousand separator:

```
In [1]: 500*500
Out[1]: 250,000
```

Can I use `'` instead?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators

Comment: @frab - thank you. Please see my update.

Comment: @MartinVegter, added a new answer, based on PEP-0378

Comment: Similar to [python - How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `'` as thousands separator in input is quite problematic because Python uses `'` to delimit strings, but you can use `_` ([PEP 515, Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/)):

[image: IPython input thousand separators]

Regarding output, this is slightly harder, but can be done using IPython extensions.

Put the following Python code in a new file at ~/.ipython/extensions/thousands_separator.py:

```py
default_int_printer = None

def print_int(number, printer, cycle):
    printer.text(f'{number:,}') # You can use `'{:,}'.format(number)` if you're using a Python version older than 3.6

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    global default_int_printer

    default_int_printer = ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(int, print_int)

def unload_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(int, default_int_printer)
```

This code tells IPython to replace the default `int` formatter with one that prints thousand separators when this extension is loaded, and restore the original when it is unloaded.

**Edit:** If you want a different separator, for instance `'`, replace the `f'{number:,}'` with `f'{number:,}'.replace(',', "'")`.

You can load the extension using the magic command `%load_ext thousands_separator` and unload it using `%unload_ext thousands_separator`, but if you want it always, you can place it in the default profile.

Run the following code in the terminal:

```
ipython3 profile create
```

It will report that a file ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py was created. Enter it, and search for the following string:

```py
## A list of dotted module names of IPython extensions to load.
#c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = []
```

Replace it with the following:

```py
# A list of dotted module names of IPython extensions to load.
c.InteractiveShellApp.extensions = [
    'thousands_separator'
]
```

This tells IPython to load this extension by default.

Done!

[image]

**Edit:** I saw that you want to a) use `'` as separator, and b) do the same for floats:

Using different separator is quite easy: just `str.replace()`:

```py
def print_int(number, printer, cycle):
    printer.text(f'{number:,}'.replace(',', "'"))
```

Doing the same for floats is also easy: just setup `print_int` so it prints floats to. I also suggest to change the name to `print_number`.

Final code:

```py
default_int_printer = None
default_float_printer = None

def print_number(number, printer, cycle):
    printer.text(f'{number:,}'.replace(',', "'"))

def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    global default_int_printer
    global default_float_printer

    default_int_printer = ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(int, print_number)
    default_float_printer = ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(float, print_number)

def unload_ipython_extension(ipython):
    ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(int, default_int_printer)
    ipython.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].for_type(float, default_float_printer)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use `'`, instead of `,` as the separator ?

Comment: Yup, updated the answer. Just use `str.replace()`

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. The update still uses `,`. And where should I use `str.replace()`?

Comment: and I am using python 3.7.3

Comment: @Chayim Friedman -  I don't understand you previous comment. Can you please explain how to use `'` instead of `,` as the separator character?

Comment: @MartinVegter Updated the answer for floats and `'` as separator

Comment: @Chayim Friedman - that is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: In Windows 10, I have to put the extention file in $HOME directory. Otherwise, ipython can't load the extension.

Answer (score 0):

After update: you can subclass int:

```
class Int(int):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{:,}".format(self)
Int(1000)
# 1,000
```

Comment: but this still does not work for `500*500`. It works for `Int(1000)`, but I get the `DeprecationWarning` each time.

Comment: edited. this at least doesn't raise any warning

Comment: thank you. Any way how to make it work for `500*500` as well?

Comment: Maybe changing the multiplication for the Int subclass... nothing immediate. Int(500*500) works though

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can achieve *all* that you are looking for without rewriting the iPython interpreter, which means changing the Python language specification, to be able to input numbers with embedded `'` characters and have them ignored. But you can achieve some of it. Subclassing the `int` class is a good start. But you should also overload the various operators you plan on using. For example:

```
class Integer(int):
    def __str__(self):
        # if you want ' as the separator:
        return "{:,}".format(self).replace(",", "'")

    def __add__(self, x):
        return Integer(int(self) + x)

    def __mul__(self, x):
        return Integer(int(self) * x)

    """
    define other operations: __sub__, __floordiv__, __mod__, __neg__, etc.
    """


i1 = Integer(2)
i2 = Integer(1000) + 4.5 * i1
print(i2)
print(i1 * (3 + i2))
```

Prints:

```
1'009
2'024
```

**Update**

It seems that for Python 3.7 you need to override the `__str__` method rather than the `__repr__` method. This works for Python 3.8 and should work for later releases as well.

**Update 2**

```
import locale

#locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '') # probably not required
print(locale.format_string("%d", 1255000, grouping=True).replace(",", "'"))
```

Prints:

```
1'255'000
```

An alternative if you have package [`Babel`](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) from the [`PyPi`](https://pypi.org/) repository:

```
from babel import Locale
from babel.numbers import format_number

locale = Locale('en', 'US')
locale.number_symbols['group'] = "'"

print(format_number(1255000, locale='en_US'))
```

Prints:

```
1'255'000
```

Or if you prefer to custom-tailor a locale just for this purpose and leave the standard `en_US` locale unmodified. **This also shows how you can parse input values:**

```
from copy import deepcopy
from babel import Locale
from babel.numbers import format_number, parse_number

my_locale = deepcopy(Locale('en', 'US'))
my_locale.number_symbols['group'] = "'"
print(format_number(1255000, locale=my_locale))
print(parse_number("1'125'000", locale=my_locale))
```

Prints:

```
1'255'000
1125000
```

Comment: it does not work for me. I get numbers without thousands separator, when I copy/paste your example exactly.

Comment: I've added an iPython Demo.

Comment: please see my `UPDATE 2`. I have made  a screeshot.

Comment: I figured out the problem for Python 3.7 (your version). See updated answer.

Comment: Booboo@ - now it works when I copy/paste your code above. But why does it not work when I simply type `500*500` in ipython?

Comment: As I mentioned in my prolog to the answer, this is a fundamental limitation to the Python language in how the type `int` behaves and I don't see a way of getting around that. However, when you enter an expression such as `Integer(7) + 3 + 2 * 7000 + 3`, the resulting type is no longer an `int` but rather the new special type `Integer`, which formats its output specially. But if it is inconvenient to use this class I will update the answer to show you how to use `format` without generating warnings.

Comment: Be sure to look at the last example that uses package `Babel` -- it has an example of parsing input values that have `'` separators.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [PEP-0378](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/), you can use the following code:

```py
a = 1200
b = 500
c = 10

#res = a
#res = a*b
res = a*b*c

dig = len(str(res))       # to figure out how many digits are required in result
print(format(res, "{},d".format(dig)))
```

It will produce:

```bash
6,000,000
```

Comment: If you want the behaviour to be implicit, i.e., if you just type in the numbers and the interpretor generates the result with thousand separator, I don't think that is currently possible!