# Is it possible to override the pretty-printing of an existing data type in SageMath?

Tags: python, sage

In IPython, using the method in [How can I configure ipython to display integers in hex format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977066/how-can-i-configure-ipython-to-display-integers-in-hex-format) , it's possible to customize how objects are printed:

```
In [1]: import ast
   ...: formatter=get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters["text/plain"]
   ...: formatter.for_type(ast.AST, lambda o, p, cycle: p.text("??"))
Out[1]: <function __main__.<lambda>(o, p, cycle)>

In [2]: x=ast.parse('1+2')

In [3]: x
Out[3]: ??
```

In SageMath, the same method does not work:

```
sage: import ast
....: formatter=get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters["text/plain"]
....: formatter.for_type(ast.AST, lambda o, p, cycle: p.text("??"))
....: x=ast.parse('1+2')
sage: x
<ast.Module object at 0x7f5750ccfaf0>
```

While for custom classes it appear to be possible to use `_repr_` or `__repr__` (the former only if the object inherit from `SageObject`):

```
sage: class A(SageObject):
....: ^Idef _repr_(self)->str:
....: ^I^Ireturn "abc"
....: A()
abc
sage: class A:
....: ^Idef __repr__(self)->str:
....: ^I^Ireturn "abc"
....: A()
abc
sage: ast.AST.__repr__=lambda x: "??"  # hack, patch Python method
sage: x=ast.parse('1+2')
sage: x
??
```

this does not work if I want to customize how an existing SageMath class e.g.

```
sage: from sage.rings.complex_interval import ComplexIntervalFieldElement
sage: ComplexIntervalFieldElement.__repr__=lambda x: "??"
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 1
----> 1 ComplexIntervalFieldElement.__repr__=lambda x: "??"

TypeError: cannot set '__repr__' attribute of immutable type 'sage.rings.complex_interval.ComplexIntervalFieldElement'
```

So, in summary, **is it possible to customize how `CIF` or other SageMath types are printed in the output**?

Comment: generally it looks impossible to monkey patch SageMath Cython things as well e.g. https://ask.sagemath.org/question/39807/monkey-patching-pari-calls/ https://ask.sagemath.org/question/53892/can-attributes-of-sage-classes-be-changed/

Answer (score 0):

This answer works in a few cases, but it has limitations.

Looking through the SageMath source code, the way pretty-printing work is:

- `SageDisplayFormatter` class `.format()` method →
- `DisplayManager` class `.displayhook()` method →
- `DisplayManager` class `._rich_output_formatter()` method →
- `BackendIPythonCommandline` class `.plain_text_formatter()` method (only if `_rich_repr_` method doesn't exist on the object) (this hardcodes `SagePrettyPrinter` to be used as `pretty_printer_class` below) →
- `BackendBase` class `._apply_pretty_printer()` method →
- constructing a new instance of `pretty_printer_class` object, and call `.pretty()` on it →
- `SagePrettyPrinter` class `.pretty()` method →
- iterate over objects in `SagePrettyPrinter.pretty_repr` list →
- `SomeIPythonRepr` class `.__call__()` method →
- lookup the type in `self._type_repr`.

Note that `SomeIPythonRepr` might be overridden, check which one is used by setting:

```py
from sage.repl.display.pretty_print import SagePrettyPrinter
SagePrettyPrinter.DEBUG=True
```

So, we modify the list (note that this accesses internal properties, which may break)

```py
sage: from sage.repl.display.pretty_print import SagePrettyPrinter
....: from sage.repl.display.fancy_repr import SomeIPythonRepr
....: import ast
....: someIPythonReprInstance = next(x for x in SagePrettyPrinter.pretty_repr
....:                                if isinstance(x, SomeIPythonRepr))
....: someIPythonReprInstance._type_repr[ast.Module] = lambda o, p, cycle: p.text("??")
```

Note that, here we cannot use `ast.AST`, because [for some reason the MRO of the object is not traversed](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/issues/36801), unlike in IPython.

Then, pretty-printing for that type will mostly work:

```
sage: ast.parse('1+2')
??
```

Another example:

```py
sage: def printAlgebraicNumber(o: AlgebraicNumber, p: SagePrettyPrinter, cycle: bool)->None:
....:     o.exactify()
....:     p.text(repr(o))
....:     if o not in QQ:
....:         p.text(' (minpoly = ')
....:         p.pretty(o.minpoly())
....:         p.text(')')
sage: QQbar(sqrt(2))
1.414213562373095? (minpoly = x^2 - 2)
```

Note that this has some performance implication -- every time an element of `QQbar` is printed, it is exactified (even if `exactify()` isn't called explicitly it's needed to check whether the element belong to the rationals anyway).

If it doesn't work, try set the `DEBUG` option (see above) to see which pretty printer is used -- if at all.

---

Potentially useful:

- `get_ipython().display_formatter` returns the `SageDisplayFormatter` instance
- `sage.repl.rich_output.get_display_manager()` returns the `DisplayManager` singleton instance, equivalently `get_ipython().display_formatter.dm`